# Issue in generating text with different color and size in csv format android

Tags: android, csv

Hello friends i want to generate csv file in my application   in following format
[image]

Whne in android i get followign type csv
[image]

My code is a follows.

```
private class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    File exportDir;
    File filerootAccount;
    String mStringGenerateFileName="";
    CSVWriter csvWrite;
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

        mCustomProgressDialog=new CustomProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mCustomProgressDialog.show("");

    }
    public Boolean doInBackground(final String... args){

        try {


            if (mStringCurrentState.equalsIgnoreCase("Month")) {


                if (mAllMethods.isSDCARDPResent()==true) {
                 exportDir = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Month");

            }
            else {
                 exportDir = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir() ,"/Month");

            }


            if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                exportDir.mkdirs();
            }
                 mStringGenerateFileName=String.valueOf(mTextViewChoiseTitle.getText().toString().trim())+".csv";

            filerootAccount = new File(exportDir, mStringGenerateFileName);
            System.out.println("filerootAccount "+filerootAccount.toString());

         System.out.println("mStringGenerateFileName "+mStringGenerateFileName);
         filerootAccount.createNewFile();


              csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filerootAccount));

                String Title="Financial Report for  "+mTextViewTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                csvWrite.writeNext(Title);
                String Title1="Property Address :  "+mStringPropertyAddress;
                csvWrite.writeNext(Title1);
                List<CartData>mListAccount=new ArrayList<CartData>();
                CartData acc=new CartData();

                String Title11="Month : "+mTextViewChoiseTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                csvWrite.writeNext(Title11);
                // this is the Column of the table and same for Header of CSV file
                String arrStracc[] ={"Unit","Type","Income","Expense"};
                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStracc);

                CartData acc1=new CartData();   
                if (mArrayListFinRentDatas.size()>0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListFinRentDatas.size(); i++) {
                        acc1.setAmount(mAllMethods.AmountForamte(mArrayListFinRentDatas.get(i).getRent_amount())); 
                        acc1.setEtype(mArrayListFinRentDatas.get(i).getIncome_cat()); 
                        mListAccount.add(acc1);


                         String arrStr[] ={mArrayListFinRentDatas.get(i).getUnit_name(), mArrayListFinRentDatas.get(i).getIncome_cat(),mAllMethods.AmountForamte(mArrayListFinRentDatas.get(i).getRent_amount())};
                         csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                    }

                }

                 if (mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.size()>0) {
                     for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.size(); i++) {
                            acc.setAmount(mAllMethods.AmountForamte(mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.get(i).getE_amount())); 
                            System.out.println("Types "+mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.get(i).getExpense_cat());
                            acc.setEtype(mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.get(i).getExpense_cat()); 
                            mListAccount.add(acc);

                             String arrStr[] ={mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.get(i).getUnit_name(), mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.get(i).getExpense_cat(),"",mAllMethods.AmountForamte(mArrayListFinExpenseDatas.get(i).getE_amount())};
                             csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                        }

                }



                 String arrStr4[] ={ "Total","",mAllMethods.AmountForamte(mStringFinalTotalIncome),mAllMethods.AmountForamte(mStringFinalTotalExpense) };
                 csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr4);

                List<CartData>mListAccount16=new ArrayList<CartData>();
                CartData acc161=new CartData();
                double profit=0.0;
                profit=Double.parseDouble(mStringFinalTotalIncome)-(Double.parseDouble(mStringFinalTotalExpense) );
                  if (profit <0) {
                    double p= Math.abs(profit);
                    acc161.setEtype("Total Profit / Loss ");
                    acc161.setAmount(String.valueOf(p));

                    mListAccount16.add(acc161);

                    for(int index=0; index < mListAccount16.size(); index++)
                    {
                         acc161=mListAccount16.get(index);
                         String arrStr[] ={ acc161.getEtype(),"","","Loss" ,mAllMethods.AmountForamte(acc161.getAmount())};
                         csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                    }
                }
                  else if (profit ==0) {
                    acc161.setEtype("Total Profit / Loss ");
                    acc161.setAmount("0.00");
                    mListAccount16.add(acc161);

                    for(int index=0; index < mListAccount16.size(); index++)
                    {
                         acc161=mListAccount16.get(index);
                         String arrStr[] ={ acc161.getEtype(),"","","" ,mAllMethods.AmountForamte(acc161.getAmount())};
                         csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                    }
                }

                else {
                    acc161.setEtype("Total Profit / Loss ");
                    acc161.setAmount(String.valueOf(profit));
                    mListAccount16.add(acc161);
                    for(int index=0; index < mListAccount16.size(); index++)
                    {
                          acc161=mListAccount16.get(index);

                         String arrStr[] ={ "Total Profit / Loss","", "","",mAllMethods.AmountForamte(acc161.getAmount())};
                         csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                    }
                }



            }


            csvWrite.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)    {

        mCustomProgressDialog.dismiss("");
        if (success){
            System.out.println("Expeort");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Financial report exported successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            mAllMethods.ShowDialog(getActivity(), "Suceess", "Export failed!", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is i want my csv format text with bold and bigger size and also with different color as per first image so how can i make it possible ? your all suggestions are appreciably.

Comment: But csv file contains only plain text instead of colors,text with styles. instead of generating csv, create files like `HTML or XLSX or DOCX`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK , is right .CSV files are just pure text file . You can not apply any formatting inside this. If you want formatting your content , you should go with .xlsx and for that libraries are available .

Comment: To expand on that, CSV is Comma Separated Values. Open the CSV in a text editor and you will see how it is formatted

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : is there any .xlsx library for android?

Comment: @Jigs : is there any library for .xlsx in android

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya: Yes [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

Comment: refer http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/format-excel-cells.html , and its the library : http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library

Comment: @Jigs as per your site reference for java it shows trial version if i integrate in future it is working or not?

Comment: I guess its free, actually I never tried its free version but it seems hard code for generate .xls so for the future use , it will work .

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to add styling, font size and colors ( text formatting) in CSV files because CSV files are just container for plain text data.

So create files like  :HTML or XLSX or DOCX,... which allow text formatting.

For creating *.xlsx* in android:

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to get the required file by using APPAche POI lib. You can find it easily just google it. :)

Once i need this and i managed to get this by using this lib.

i hope this snippets will help you achieve what you want.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet1 = null;
CellStyle cell = null;
// Cell style for header row
cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
Font boldFont = wb.createFont();
boldFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
cs.setFont(boldFont); 

sheet1 = wb.createSheet(sheetname);
cell.setCellValue("Colum name");
cell.setCellStyle(cs);
sheet1.setColumnWidth(size, (15 * 500));
```